# Regex vevo URL video-id

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net

I want to match the video-ID from a vevo.com URL.

Example URL:

```
http://www.vevo.com/watch/arash/she-makes-me-go/SE2VJ1200401
```

The ID would be `SE2VJ1200401`. I tried the pattern `/(.*){12}` but that did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are probably aiming for is:

```
/(.{12})
```

But that will also match `//www.vevo.c` and `/watch/arash/`.  If you want to limit it to just the last part of the URL, you could use:

```
/(.{12})$
```

However, you may want to consider using `\w` (any word character) or `\S` (any non-whitespace character) instead of `.`  For instance:

```
/(\w{12})$
/(\S{12})$
```

Answer (score 1):

Those VEVO ids are actually part of a standard called the [International Standard Recording Code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Standard_Recording_Code), which has a strict formatting, which can help your regex be more specific.

One that I've used is this:

```js
// 2 alphabetical chars, 3 alphanumeric, two digits, then 5 digits
var regex = /([A-Z]{2}[A-Z0-9]{3}\d{2}\d{5})/;
```

This also allows for URLs that end in a query string or a hash.